# WCF Client error: “The address of the security token issuer is not specified”

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

[image: Game]

error occur: "The address of the security token issuer is not specified. An explicit issuer address must be specified in the binding for target 'net.tcp://localhost:5054/player' or the local issuer address must be configured in the credentials."

there is any wrong in credentials?

have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Binding setup with an IssuedToken credential type:

```
<issuedTokenParameters keyType="SymmetricKey" tokenType="" />
```

use next child node as issuer.

For that follow this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924499.aspx

This allows you to specify the address of an secure token server that the client should use to negotiate the token.

`<issuer>` is written as follows:

```
<issuer address="https://server/secure token server" binding="<binding type>" bindingConfiguration="<binding configuration for the secure token server>" />
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IPlayerService">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="IssuedToken"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IUserService">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="IssuedToken"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IPublicService">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>

Comment: this is my binding and token.   this is my endpoint  "  <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5054/player" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IPlayerService" contract="PlayerService.IPlayerService" name="NetTcpBinding_IPlayerService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="pident.cloudapp.net"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>"